# Sell Product - Customer get Coupon Code that will expire after 6 months of sell date

Tags: magento-1.9, product, magento-1.8, customer, coupon-codes

I read `document/google/tested` on my **Magento 1.8.1+1.9.2CE** but I can't get it to work:

I have a product like **sku123**. 
The customer buys it and gets a `coupon code` for free (`10€` discount for the next 6 months).
But the coupon code should have a expire date: **6 months after sale date**.

I found no way to do this. Modules bring **x-features**, but not this one: expire-date that is **6 months after the sale date**.

Can anybody give me a hint how this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Magento can't do this out of the box indeed. You'll have to create or buy a module to achieve this. I've done this in the past with the [Amasty follow-up email module](https://amasty.com/magento-follow-up-email.html)